# Send sms to phone number using GUPSHUP and nodejs

Tags: node.js, sms, gupshup

I need help in sending sms to user using nodejs and Gupshup.io . I'm facing difficulty understanding their documentation.

Comment: Hi, please be more specific with the problems, share snippets of the code that you want to get to work, but cannot, and ask for what you specifically want to do. If you have difficulty understanding the docs, paste the parts of the doc you have difficulty understandng and ask for clarification on them instead. Initially, watch a course/read through articles that can help you get started.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Khurram Shahzad

I work as a chatbot developer for Gupshup, please let me know what you don't understand.

Either way, here I'll share the snipet code to send an sms in node.js with our API.

```
const { default: axios } = require('axios');
/*
Variables to replace
YOUR_API_KEY => The unique identifier for a Gupshup account.
YOUR_APP_ID=> The unique identifier for an app. An app's appid can be found in the cURL request generated on the dashboard.
*/
const sendMessage = (msg, phone, callbackFunc) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams()
    params.append('destination', phone);
    params.append('message', msg);
    params.append('source', 'GSDSMS'); //Required only for india

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'apikey': YOUR_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }

    axios.post('http://api.gupshup.io/sms/v1/message/:YOUR_APP_ID', params, config)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('Message sent');
            callbackFunc(result.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            callbackFunc(err);
        })
}

module.exports = {
    sendMessage
}
```